# Automatically assigning bins for vector graduated classes within a given range (QGIS 3)

Tags: qgis, style

Is there a way to assign graduated bins automatically for vectors within a given range in QGIS3?

I am trying to produce a series of maps which share a same legend, but do not necessarily exhibit all the same classes within each of their ranges:
[image: Multiple maps sharing a same legend]

For this first map, I assigned bins manually so that the entire range would be covered, but this is a time consuming process that I would have to repeat for each class and for each set of maps.

[image: Having to manually input ranges for each class is time consuming.]

QGIS seems to automatically bin ranges from the smallest to the largest value present within a particular attribute, but I'd like to know if there is a way to override that so that I can provide a lower and upper value and automatically bin them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workaround

1. Create a new polygon layer.
2. Add a field with the same name as the field you'll be using to classify the other vector layers.
3. Add two polygons. Give one polygon the minimum value for that attribute, and give the other the maximum value.
4. Set up a graduated style for the scratch layer with the desired number of classes (bins).

   [image]
5. Copy and paste the style from this layer to all the other layers. The class boundaries will be copied along with the style.
6. Use the two-polygon layer for your legend.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about doing something similar as a last resort, I guess I'll go for it.